# What functions are symmetric about the plane y = z?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, symmetry

How can you algebraically check if a function in 3-space has reflection symmetry about the plane y = z? What are some examples of functions with this symmetry?

I have tried graphing functions where f(a,b) = f(-b, -a) and have been unsuccessful. I know that for functions with symmetry about the plane y= x, f(a,b) =f(b,a) for all a, b

Comment: Are your functions $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: I ask the same thing as @Kurt G. in a different way: is the equation of your surface of type $z=f(x,y)$ (explicit) or $\varphi(x,y,z)=0$ (implicit) ?

Comment: To reiterate previous comments, you seem to be asking when the surface (not function) $z=f(x,y)$ is symmetric about $y=z$. This means that whenever $(x,y,f(x,y))$ is a point on the graph, then $(x,f(x,y),y)$ must be on the graph. So $f(x,f(x,y))=y$ for every $y$ is the necessary condition. I suspect you intended a different question. Please clarify.